# Why is my user not signed in when returning from a Paypal payment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, devise

After a user has signed up for an account, they are automatically signed in.

Then they have the option of "Activating their account" to unlock the app's features. The account activation leads them to a Paypal gateway. After successfully completing payment they are redirected back to an invoice page. However there is no current user session on the invoice page. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? the code is below

I'm using devise to manage authentication.

Here's the User Model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, presence: true

  serialize :notification_params, Hash
  def paypal_url(return_path)
    values = {
        business: "seller@seller.com",
        cmd: "_xclick",
        upload: 1,
        return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
        invoice: id,
        amount: 20,
        item_name: "Online Store",
        item_number: 1,
        quantity: '1',
        notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
    }
    "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end

end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users #, :controllers => {:registrations => 'memberships'}
  root 'pages#dashboard'
  get 'home' => 'pages#dashboard'

  devise_scope :user do 
    post 'invoice' => "memberships#show"
    post 'hook' => "memberships#hook"
  end
```

Here's the controller managing the payment/webhook

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = current_user

  end

  protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
  def hook
    params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @user = User.find params[:invoice]
      @user.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

Here's the show page for the invoice post, keep in mind it's been simplified for testing:

```
%section#course-content
  %section#ruby
    %section.detailed-syllabus
      .wrapper-inside
        %h3.title Course invoice
      .columns.clearfix
        .left{style: "padding-left:100px;"}
          %p#notice= notice
          %p
            - if user_signed_in?
              %strong Email:
              = current_user.first_name
            - else
              %strong Invalid User Session
```

Let me know if there's anything else you need to see. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some Research I found an answer by Stefan Wrobel on a google forum.

> " Ok, I figured it out at last. For rails 3.0.4 and above, the automatic
> CSRF protection on forms will invalidate the session if any action
> other than GET is done and the authenticity token isn't provided.
> Since there is no way to have Paypal send the authenticity token,
> there are two ways around this:
>
> 1. Allow Paypal to keep its default
>    behavior and POST back to your site. In this case you can disable
>    forgery protection using protect_from_forgery :except =>
>    [:controller_action_name] although this could be considered a
>    potential security hole if you are accepting Paypal's payment data
>    transfer information without verifying it somehow since someone could
>    just POST bogus data and complete a transaction.
> 2. Force Paypal to send
>    the user back via GET by setting the web payments standard rm
>    parameter to 1 which forces GET (rm stands for return method, and must
>    be used in conjunction with the return parameter to specify the URL).
>    See here:
>    https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B
>
> Good luck, hope this helps! It took way too long to figure this one
> out..."